# Is xkb a part of xlib standard?

Tags: linux, xlib, window-managers, xserver

Is `xkb` a part of `xlib` standard? Can I use it in my applications, without any problems on all the "xorg-driven" systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have not found up if `xkb` is part of `xlib` standard. But I have found up, that I can use `xkb` everywhere where I can use `xlib`. According to this `Xlib`'s developers [post](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/xorg/guide/extensions/#index1h2):

> Programmers writing against the Xlib API will find some Xlib keyboard functions now call XKB support under the hood. Other Xlib keyboard calls are deprecated and should be replaced in applications by calls to replacement XKB functions in Xlib.

So, you can use `xkb` almost everywhere. (Almost because it is possible to build x server without the extension, but in real life probably you can not meet it.